# Delphi XE2 Debugger not working properly

Tags: delphi, debugging, delphi-xe2

since a few days, Delphi xe2 debugger stopped working like should be. Let me explain, I set a breakpoint in editor and hit F9, the ide stops on breakpoint as should be, everything ok. But when I hit F7 or F8 the line or the execution does not advance. I hit it several times, and nothing. If I set a breakpoint, lets say, x lines ahead in the same procedure/method and hit F9 it stops in the new breakpoint as usual, but hitting f7 or f8 not work, as before. All debug properties are set it the project configuration, as must be set.

Is a IDE thing, because I started a new empty project, just 1 form, a button and 3 Showmessages in the Onclick event of the button. No recursion, no events firing, nothing.

I've unistalled Ddevextensions, idefixpack, gexperts and cnwizards and the problem persists. The last thing is unistalling delphi and reinstalling again, but is a last resort. Expect to be clear in my explanation,  English is not my primary language. 
Greetings from Isla de Margarita, Venezuela

Comment: Have you tried using menu options or toolbar buttons to step through your code instead of the shortcut keys? If those work, then the problem might be shortcut configuration. Either another application or component interfering with hotkeys, or Keymapping in your Editor Options.

Comment: Yes, was the first think I do. In both cases, with the hotkey and with the toolbar buttons, the screen flickrs like normally do. If I press F9 the program continues normal execution

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand? You say: "screen flickrs like normally do". Does that mean the toolbar button works?

Comment: Not, it doesn't work with the toolbar. What I want to say is that when I press F8 or click on the toolbar button, the screen flickrs or refresh I don't know how to say it, but the cursor and the background bar of the current execution line stay in the same place no matter how many times I hit F8 or press the toolbar button. Excuse me for not being clear

Comment: Don't stress about not being clear. You're making more effort than a lot of other people. Unfortunately, I'm at a loss. If the problem is corrupted binaries, then reinstall might be the only option. The only other thing I can think of trying is ensure you have appropriate permission. (I.e. Admin user) Debugging does require elevated privileges; but if that were the problem, I'd expect breakpoints not to work at all.

Answer (score 3):

Remove all DCU's from project directory, also remove *.identcache, MAP files.
Rebuild project, than compile it. Also check, remote debug symbols(*.rsm) must be disabled(if you don't use it).

Answer (score 0):

Nothing of the above worked for me.
The simplest way I've found is to copy the file source code from Delphi IDE to the notepad and then copy it again from the notepad to the Delphi IDE and all worked fine for me. it may be some problematic hidden characters.